# Unable to Convert string to date/time using TO_DATE in Informatica specifically for time from 0000 hrs to 0059 hrs

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

I am converting the string in to date using the expression TO_DATE('111120110045','DDMMYYYYHHMI'). All other value fo HH it is converting to perfect date except for 00 as it is given in the above expression.

If I am changing the expression TO_DATE('111120110145','DDMMYYYYHHMI') it is converting properly.

What might be the problem..Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to TO_DATE('111120110045','DDMMYYYYHH24MI'). 00 hours is only valid in 24 hour time format.